# Need help making file i/o program using Python

Tags: python, encryption, file-io, cryptography

Make a Cryptography program as follows.(Add file i/o to it)

1. You should have (at least) two functions: encrypt and decrypt.
2. Enhance your main routine to:
   a. welcome the user
   b. ask the user whether (s)he wants to encrypt or decrypt
   c. ask the user what file the encrypted message is to be written to/read from
   d. if encrypting:
   ask for the message to encrypting
   ask for the key
   call encrypt to create cipher text
   open the file
   write the cipher test to the file
   close the file
   inform the user that the cipher text (displayed) has been stored to the file (make sure to mention the file's name!)
   e. if decrypting: ask for the key open the file read the cipher test from the file close the file call decrypt to decipher the cipher text display the message for the user
   f. ask if the user would like to perform another task
   g. if so, go to (b)
   h. otherwise quit

Here are the codes I need to add in the program:

```
#open file to write record(s). It will create the file if new!
f = open("temp.txt", "w") 
f.write("Hello!\n")
f.close

#open file to read this time
f = open("temp.txt", "r")
line = f.readline()
print(line)
f.close

#try binary read...
f = open("temp.txt", "rb")
line = f.readlines()
print(line)
f.close
```

Here is what I have already (Everything but the input/output functions for the files):

```
# Caesar Cipher

MAX_KEY_SIZE = 26

def getMode():
    while True:
        mode = input("Do you wish to encrypt or decrypt a message?").lower()
        if mode in "encrypt e decrypt d". split():
            return mode
        else:
##            print("Enter either "encrypt" or "e" or "decrypt" or "d".')
def getMessage():
    return input("Enter you message")

def getKey():
    key = 0
    while True
        key = int(input("Enter a key number (1-26)"))
        if (key >=1 and key <= MAX_KEY_SIZE):
            return key

def getTranslatatedMessage(mode, messafe, key):
    if mode[0] == "d":
        key = -key
    translated = ""

    for symbol in message:
        if symbol.isalpha():
            num = ord(symbol)
            num += key

            if symbol.isupport():
                if num > ord("Z"):
                  num -= 26
                elif num < ord("A"):
                  num += 26
            elif symbol.islower():
                if num < ord("z"):
                  num += 26
                elif num < ord("a"):
                  num += 26

            translated += chr(num)
        else:
            translated += symbol
    return translated
mode = getMode()
message = getMessage()
key = getKey()
```

My question is where do I add the above codes into the encrypt/decrypt program?

Comment: So what is your question? It sounds like "could you complete my home work?". You shall provide specific question.

Comment: I made the encrypt/decrypt program and it runs perfectly but now I have to make it ask the user for a file and I know the codes to do that, I just don't know where to put them.

Comment: You shall write this specific question to the end of your question. It might be like "how to ask for user input specifying a file name" or something like that (you know better than me).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't ask your question.

You can find informations about input/output in [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Basically, you can open a file, write into it and close it as following:

```
    f = open("myfile", "w")
    text = "something"
    f.write(text)
    f.close()
```

To deal with binary data it is possible to specify binary format "wb" for writing or "rb" for reading and conversions like:

```
    f = open("binfile", "rb")
    buffer = f.read(2)
    print hex(ord(buffer[0]))
```

There are other ways to pack/unpack binary files in Python but you must ask a more precise question.

Comment: Sorry, my question is that I don't know where to add the file i/o codes in the program.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to proceed a file instead of a message provided by the user.
So in **getMessage** you should return the content of the read file

```
    def getMessage():
        f = open("temp.txt", "r")
        text = f.read()
        f.close()
        return text
```

And you write to file the translated message.

Comment: So I replace:  def getMessage():
    return input("Enter you message") with def getMessage():
        f = open("temp.txt", "r")
        text = f.read()
        f.close()
        return text

Comment: I added the code you said but when it asked me if I wanted to encrypt or decrypt I put encrypt and it gave me an error message: Do you wish to encrypt or decrypt a message? encrypt

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Ally/Downloads/EncryptDecrypt Program", line 50, in <module>
    message = getMessage()
  File "/Users/Ally/Downloads/EncryptDecrypt Program", line 13, in getMessage
    f = open("temp.txt", "r")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'temp.txt'

Comment: It seems it's your need. But I think you should first understand what you want to do, maybe writing an algorithm before implementing it in any language

Comment: The error is obvious!!! The file temp.txt is supposed to exist and contain the text you want to encrypt.

Comment: I won't write the program for you. As I told you, try first to understand what you need to do

Comment: So I want to have the user write their encrypt message in a file called temp.txt. I made a file named that. Now I want to be able to open and close the file so it can be decrypted by someone else. Is this correct? –

Comment: But you should ask to user the name of the file like : filename = input("Enter your file name"). Then open it instead of "temp.txt" -> open(filename, "r")...

Comment: thank you for that, can you just tell me how to open the file